# Applying DataView on DataTable with duplicate values

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

I have a table and one of its columns has multiple duplicates. I want to filter all the rows that have the same value on the column at once. I tried to use the `getFormattedValue()` method which gets the value of a column and then I applied the usual code for DataView. When I click on the row, it disappears all the rows of the table except of the selected one and it doesn't filter all the rows with the duplicate value on the column. Here is my code so far:

```
var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
var items = " ";
table.draw(dataTable, {width: 1000, height: 300});
google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'select',
    function(event) {
        var selection = table.getSelection();
        var view = new google.visualization.DataView(dataTable);
        for(i = 0; i < row.length; i++){
            var items == dataTable.getFormattedValue(i, i);
            if(items = "anti-social-behaviour"){
                console.log("if statement");
                view.setRows([selection[i].row]);
                table.draw(view, []);
            }
        }
    });
```

If anyone could spot the problem it wold be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see many problems with this code.  First off, where is `row` coming from in this line?

```
for(i = 0; i < row.length; i++){
```

Second, you are testing the formatted value of `(i, i)` in the data set, which checks `(0, 0)`, then `(1, 1)`, then `(2, 2)`, etc. instead of checking an entire row or column.  Third, on these lines:

```
view.setRows([selection[i].row]);
table.draw(view, []);
```

You are setting the rows to be used in the view to the `row` property of the `i`th element in `selection` (which may be `undefined`, since there is nothing stopping `i` from growing larger than the length of `selection`).  The `setRows` method sets the *entire* row set to use for the view, so each time you call that, you are setting the rows to (a maximum of) 1 row, and then drawing the table with the view, which is why you see only 1 row in the table.

If you want to filter the table to display only rows that have a value matching the value in the selected row, this is what you need to use:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'select', function(event) {
    var selection = table.getSelection();
    if (selection.length) {
        var filterView = new google.visualization.DataView(dataTable);
        filterView.setColumns([{
            type: 'string',
            sourceColumn: 1, // set this column to be whatever column you want to check for duplicate values
            calc: 'stringify'
        }]);
        var value = filterView.getValue(selection[0].row, 0);
        var rows = filterView.getFilteredRows([{column: 0, value: value}]);
        var view = new google.visualization.DataView(dataTable);
        view.setRows(rows);
        table.draw(view, []);
    }
});
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. I was not aware of the `setColumn()` method. Cheers!